# VBA Delete Rows Autofilter NOT BLANK

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to filter my data and delete the entire row if the cell CB is not empty (i want to keep only empty cells). Sometimes it can happen that all my cells are blank

My code is:

```
Sub Part2()


Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter

 Selection.AutoFilter Field:=80, Criteria1:="<>"

If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then

        ActiveSheet.Range("2:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Selection.AutoFilter

End If
 If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

However, when I have cells that are not empty, it skips directly to End If and it is not deleting the rows at all. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried around myself and found this code to work (sorry for the filter changements, but you can easily set them according to your needs):

```
Sub Part2()


Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Basel"

If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
'If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then

    ActiveSheet.Range("2:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count). _
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.AutoFilter

End If
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Note how I simplified your first if condition (below is your original one). Please let me know, if this works for your purposes.